# How can I generate images from LaTeX without using ghostscript/ImageMagick?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, inline-image

My question here is about generating images from LaTeX source blocks in .org files

The following source block (edited down to a simple use case) works fine and produces a .pdf, but this does not appear in the document when using `org-display-inline-images`.

```
#+header: :packages '("\\usepackage{tikz} \\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} ")
#+begin_src latex :file figure.pdf :results raw file
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,thick,dashed] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
    \draw[blue, thick, dashed] (0.5, 0) circle (1.5cm);
    \path (-1.5,-1.5) node[]{$Test$};
    \path (2,2) node[] {$Another$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

Changing `:file figure.pdf` to `:file figure.png` results in a tiny image with all the content crammed in together.
(*CORRECTION*: all the text is jammed together, without the text commands, there is nothing in the image)

If I follow one of the examples in [the documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html) and add the header

```
#+header: :imagemagick yes :iminoptions -density 600 :imoutoptions -geometry 400
```

I get the error message

```
Converting pdffile file convert -density 600 /tmp/babel-pv17K3/latex-KCde1K.pdf -geometry 400 figure.png...
convert: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `gs' @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/382.
convert: no images defined `figure.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3322.
```

I worked out that this is due to an old security issue (e.g. [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900396/imagemagick-ghostscript-and-pdfs) in `ghostscript`, and can be fixed by editing `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml`.
I've tried it myself and **the fix works**. However, I'm a cautious guy, and would prefer not to edit `policy.xml`. So,

**Question: Is there some alternative to `ghostscript/ImageMagick` for generating .png images in (LaTeX) org-babel code blocks?**

For example, the LaTeX previews generated in org-mode come out alright, and are in .png format, it seems that these previews are generated via `dvipng`, see [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html). Is there any way to add options to `dvipng` via headers to make the `.png` images come out correctly?

I've also generated .png images from Python source blocks, using the `matplotlib` library, which doesn't (apparently?) use `ghostscript` as a backend for generating .png files.

Comment: FWIW, changing to `:file figure.png` does *NOT* produce a tiny image for me: the resulting png shows two circles, blue with diameter 3cm and red with diameter 2cm, exactly as specified. Although Org mode does its best to hide it, the command it executed to convert the pdf to png was `convert -density 134.39999999999998 -trim -antialias /tmp/orgtexGEv8Ol.pdf -quality 100 /tmp/orgtexGEv8Ol.png`.

Comment: @NickD Thanks - I believe you helped me on an earlier question involving latex image previews. Just FYI, I am doing this in a completely blank `.org` file without any `#+LaTeX_HEADERS` involved to makes sure nothing is going wrong, or latex templates, so that removes one explanation as to why the images are tiny for me but not for you...

Comment: @NickD do you have something in your `init.el` that automatically picks `ImageMagick`? And does your `/etc/ImageMagick-X/policy.xml` allow for ghostscript, or gives read-write permission for `PDF` files?

Comment: I do use the `imagemagick` method in `org-preview-latex-process-alist`, i.e. my `org-preview-latex-default-process` is `imagemagick`. I have not modified any settings in ` `org-preview-latex-process-alist`.  My `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` has a `policymap` section with everything commented out: I believe I have not touched it since installation (running on Fedora 33).

Comment: Trying the `dvipng` method instead fails: `dvipng` compl;ains `This is dvipng 1.17 Copyright 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-Ake Larsson
[1 <raw PostScriptdvipng warning: PostScript environment contains DVI commands....` and produces a PNG that cannot be displayed, although it returns a 0 exit status...

Comment: @NickD Thanks, I will keep looking at `org-preview-latex-process-alist` and see what I can do. I am running Manjaro, which uses the Arch default for `policy.xml` described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ImageMagick) .

Comment: @NickD Also, I copied the example code into a new file in a new folder and the .png produced was blank. It turns out I was missing text in the `tikz` code. If I run the amended example, all the text is jammed in together, but the circles do not appear. So it seems that `dvipng` can handle text, but not "shapes" constructed in `tikz`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130778/discussion-between-nickd-and-nonreligious).